# how to create cordova .jar file for android?

Tags: cordova, android-webview

I am following this guide https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/webview.html

it says Navigate to the Android package's /framework directory and run ant jar.

How can I reach that folder? I cant see any folder named framework also im using cordova cli

Answer (score 9):

You have to download the cordova-android source code from

https://github.com/apache/cordova-android

You have the framework folder there.

But if you just want to embed a cordova webview you don't really need the .jar anymore, that tutorial is outdated, you can follow this one 
http://docs.phonegap.com/develop/1-embed-webview/android/